# Why batches of same items are not next to each other?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I loot lots of alcohol, and never really paid it any attention until recently, when I wanted to earn some coins from selling part of the huge stash I collected. I was amazed to see this mess:

> [image]

This was taken in a Shop while selling, but it is the same when I just open the Inventory. All the marked items are exactly the same: same name, same price.

I tried to re-order the items by type, no change  - still random mess.

I understand that each type of item got its own "batch amount", however how come the exact same items are not next to each other? Is there a way to fix this?

This still happens even after a major redesign of the Inventory that has been introduced as part of patch 1.20 released in May 2016.

Comment: @Timelord64 yes I assumed the same, but would like to see a table listing stack details of each possible item, or type of items. (e.g. weak alcohol vs. strong alcohol etc.)

Comment: @Timelord64 not really, the main issue is the wrong sort, or missing sort - it's all in a mess. Maybe I will remove the part about stacking itself, or post it as new question. At first I thought it's related, but now thinking about it, it's most likely two separate things anyway.

Comment: I see what you mean. Be ware, it might come down to "the developer a made it that way" for why they stack like that. That said, there could still be a solution to that problem, if your playing on computer.

Comment: @Timelord64 no computer, PS4. Thanks! :)

Comment: Alchemy and Crafting also has this problem, although everything stacks to 100 there so you don't see it as much.

Comment: Thanks @greg I didn't notice, will try reaching 100 in something to see.

Comment: Wagering a guess, I'd say it has to do with how the code handles picking up new items.  Something like `if (alreadyHave and stackNotFull) then addToStack; else makeNewStack;` and it throws a new item at the end of the list/table that tracks inventory.  Whenever you open inventory, it just reads through the data from top to bottom and doesn't resort it to group by name

Comment: I don't think you will get a very good answer here. You should rather take this to CD Projekt Red. All we can tell you is that it was implemented like this rather than the way you'd like it.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray well, looks like a bug to me, or something I missed, just want to confirm it either way. (e.g. known bug that might be fixed in some future update, or explanation in case I missed something)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I honestly don't think this is a bug, but rather a weak design choice. This can be observed in almost all RPGs. You stack something to full and the new stack occupies the first free slot. You could try to write a mod up that changes that if you are playing on PC.There wasn't any announcement about changing this.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray I don't care about the stack itself, just about the total lack of consistency, i.e. each item got a different max stack amount, and the stacks don't appear next to each other. (hence making it really hard to know how many of each item I have.)

Answer (score 1):

This way of inventory management is due to poor design of inventory stacking [a prominent design flaw].  It would seem these items are added to your inventory based on when you received them, rather than by type or stack amount.  There is no way to fix this as it is part of the game code itself, and not a "bug".

As @Crowley Astray had mentioned.  If you are still quite upset about this design flaw, you can reach out to [CD Projekt Red Support](http://en.cdprojektred.com/contact-support/) and let them know.  There is a chance that they have received complaints on this before, and may patch it in the future.

I hope this helps out!

Comment: Thanks, though I doubt they still fix non critical things at this point, more likely they work on the next Witcher... :)